# how to open C# winforms in the same window like in windows every folder opens in a same window etc

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i am developing a c# application which contains round about 30 winforms. every form perform some functionality and pass the data to the second form. the problem is that every form opened in a new window and at the end i have to close them all. All I want is that all the forms open in the one/main form like in windows when we open multiple forms it opens in a same window. To goto i am using this:

```
form1 f1 = new form1 ();
f1.showdialogue().
```

Comment: "All I want is that all the forms open in the one/main form like in windows when we open multiple forms it opens in a same window." As mentioned by Micky Duncan this is not very clear as to what you mean. If you could post a screenshot of what you're talking about then we'd have a much better idea of what it is you want.

Answer (score 1):

> *like in windows every folder opens in a same window etc*

Are you describing *Windows Explorer*?

Windows Explorer uses the *Windows Shell* for browsing [shell namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144090(v=vs.85).aspx).  Each namespace exposes a series of logical folders and folder items.  Each folder can have ShellViews specially tailored to display particlar content.  A view does not have to be "folders or files" but also printers; network computers; or Fonts to name a few.  *Microsoft Management Console* (MMC) follows a similar pattern.

### Method

You can do something similar in c#.

1. First break-up your app into a logical collection of areas/parts/components/folders
2. Each area has a corresponding **UserControl**
3. When you "browse" or "open" an area you create the **UserControl** for that area and display it
4. When moving to another area (or going back) you display the next appropriate area

In addition have you thought of a **page-navigation** style app (web-style; *Microsoft Money*) and instead of popping up new windows, you just embed a **UserControl** into the main window. This control takes up most of the UI space.  There is no "z-order" because there are no overlapping windows.

Then you could have **Forward** and **Back** buttons.

Lookup *[Inductive User-interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728824(v=vs.85).aspx) design* on MSDN as well as Shell namespace programming if only to get ideas.

### Related

A bit off topic since you are using WinForms, but take a look at [WPF Page Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478(v=vs.110).aspx) to get ideas there too.

Comment: If I may add also to your good answer, he can use an IDE control also

Answer (score 0):

you can use MDIParent for this type problem.
and you can close any number of form my getting all child Form of MdiParent Form.